# There is no possible way that this wall is load bearing, right?

Tags: drywall, walls, structural, construction, load-bearing

The wall runs parallel to the joists, and has no joist or beam above it. It is impossible for this to be load bearing, right?

I’m surprised they used a double top plate for this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A double top plate does more than just weight/load bearing.  It can be a spacer/filler, it keeps the wall straight if the lower plate is in two pieces.  Would like to know how it is anchor to the ceiling since it looks like it misses the joist above.

Comment: @crip659 doesn’t seem to be anchored at all. Well you look in the stud space above it, it’s totally empty space.

Comment: It might have some blocking between the joists.  Just drywall does not hold a wall that well if someone leans against it.  I would place that wall as not load bearing.

Comment: What is on the left side (near the staircase)?

Comment: @unhandledexcepsean that’s a closet wall

Comment: All, **double top plates are _standard_**. All walls must be the same height! The only place you'll see singles is in the basement, where walls are built after the slab is poured and need to be custom heights due to floor level variations. To do otherwise would require two lengths of pre-cut studs, which would be so confusing as to negate any material cost savings.

Comment: The duplicate I linked covers this completely. Amateur framers should stop speculating and confusing the situation.